# Running docker -d fails on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

I am working on a fresh VM delivered by Host Europe that matches the description on
https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#ubuntu-trusty-1404-lts-64-bit
(so Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 (LTS) (64-bit), 3.13.0 Linux kernel).
After installing the docker.io package `docker ps` fails with
"Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?"
When running `docker -d` I get:

```
INFO[0000] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
INFO[0000] +job init_networkdriver()
inappropriate ioctl for device
INFO[0000] -job init_networkdriver() = ERR (1)
FATA[0000] inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Apparently *this error happens as well when the docker service tries to start via upstart*.
I also tried it with the latest docker package according to "Docker-maintained Package Installation" in the above-mentioned description.

Here is the more detailed ouptput using `docker -D -d`:

```
INFO[0000] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
DEBU[0000] libdevmapper(3): ioctl/libdm-iface.c:363 (-1) /dev/mapper/control: open failed: Operation not permitted
DEBU[0000] libdevmapper(3): ioctl/libdm-iface.c:415 (-1) Failure to communicate with kernel device-mapper driver.
DEBU[0000] libdevmapper(3): ioctl/libdm-iface.c:417 (-1) Check that device-mapper is available in the kernel.
DEBU[0000] Using graph driver vfs
DEBU[0000] Creating images graph
DEBU[0000] Restored 0 elements
DEBU[0000] Creating repository list
INFO[0000] +job init_networkdriver()
DEBU[0000] Creating bridge docker0 with network 172.17.42.1/16
DEBU[0000] setting bridge mac address = true
inappropriate ioctl for device
INFO[0000] -job init_networkdriver() = ERR (1)
FATA[0000] inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Ideas anybody? Thanks in advance. (Seems like a "deadend" to me after lots of successfull "dockerizing" on local VMs.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably your hoster doesn't provide cgroups. That happens sometimes depending on the kind virtualization they use.
I have the same problem with www.stratro.de

Thats when `cat /proc/cgroups` returns an empty table.

You can see more here: https://mannlinstones.wordpress.com/2014/08/12/docker-v-server-strato-final-results/

Comment: Thanks - that's exaclty what I figured by now. This renders **Docker a JOKE** in practice in many cases, cause so many small IT-businesses rely on VM-providers such as Host Europe or Strato (all over Europe). Unfortunately I figured this out **AFTER** I dockered my entire infrastructure... Grrr. A few **WARNINGs on [link](www.docker.com) would be the least to expect**.

Comment: I just found out that https://www.leaseweb.com/ provides a virtualisation that is runs with docker. They have datacenters in US, NL and DE. Maybe that suites you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the runtime dependencies from Docker -> [Check runtime dependencies](https://docs.docker.com/installation/binaries)? It is defentliy a problem with your [filesystem](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/multi/kernel_user_space_howto-4.html) maybe it is related to [this](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4568) problem.

From Docker:

> a properly mounted cgroupfs hierarchy (having a single, all-encompassing "cgroup" mount point is not sufficient)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you initial suggestions. I checked the runtime dependencies - they are ok, except for the cgroups structure: `less /proc/cgroups` returns an empty table (except for the table headers). However I have no idea how to fix this - I also lack deeper background knowledge on cgroups. The packages `cgroup-lite` and `apparmor` are (obviously) installed...